# Trivial cipher + some linguistics

Tags: cipher, language

I think that the title says enough. I would like to apologise for probable mistakes, but I hope I did not do them in the cipher and they should not matter much in the second part.

What does it mean?:

> 4 1 18 _ 9 18 19 _ ♦ 4 5 20 19 14 ˌ ¿ 8 8 9 18 18 5 13 _ ♦ 18 9 5 ? * 11 5 20 19 5 _ 18 16 17 5 22 5 13 _ ♦ 4 5 20 19 14 _ 9 13 _ ♦ 4 5 20 19 14 11 1 13 4 ( 20 13 4 _ 9 13 _ ♦ 24 5 18 19 5 17 17 5 9 22 ˌ 20 13 4 _ 1 20 22 _ 9 13 : ♦ 14 8 8 5 9 6 6 ˌ 20 13 4 _ ♦ 11 20 10 18 5 13 2 20 17 3 ) * 9 22 _ 15 21 21 5 ˛ 4 1 18 18 _ ♦ 18 9 5 _ 8 5 17 18 19 7 5 13 _ 4 1 18 * 9 22 _ 2 5 13 20 6 6 5 _ 4 1 18 _ ♦ 3 17 9 5 22 9 14 5 _ 1 11 21 1 2 5 19 _ 12 9 19 _ 12 5 9 13 5 17 _ 5 9 3 5 13 5 13 _ 15 17 19 15 3 17 1 21 9 5 _ 20 13 4 _ 9 13 19 5 17 16 20 13 10 19 9 15 13 * 9 22 _ 18 16 17 5 22 5 _ ♦ 4 5 20 19 14 _ 13 9 22 19 _ 18 7 17 _ 3 20 19 ˌ 1 2 5 17 _ 4 1 18 _ 9 18 19 _ 4 9 5 _ 2 5 10 1 13 13 19 5 18 19 5 _ 18 16 17 1 22 5 _ 9 13 _ 4 5 17 _ 8 8 5 11 19 ˛ 4 9 5 _ 9 22 _ 12 1 3 * 9 22 _ 15 21 21 5 ˛ 4 1 18 18 _ 9 22 _ 13 9 22 19 _ 6 20 _ 8 9 5 11 5 _ 21 7 11 5 17 _ 3 5 12 1 22 19 _ 7 1 2 5 ⁂ 4 9 5 _ 19 9 5 17 5 _ 18 9 13 4 _ 6 20 12 _ 2 5 9 18 16 9 5 11 : 12 1 5 20 18 5 17 ˌ 10 1 6 6 5 13 ˌ 20 13 4 5 ˌ 10 20 5 5 ˌ 20 13 4 _ 23 5 17 4 5 ⁂ 1 12 _ 5 13 4 5 _ 5 9 13 _ 8 8 5 9 13 1 22 19 18 - 11 9 5 4 ( 4 9 5 _ 9 22 _ 13 9 22 19 _ 3 1 13 6 _ 8 5 17 18 8 5 ) ⁑ ¡ 18 19 9 11 11 5 _ 13 1 22 19 ˌ 5 9 11 9 3 5 _ 13 1 22 19 ! * // 1 11 11 5 18 _ 14 11 1 5 21 19 ˌ 5 9 13 18 1 12 _ 8 8 1 22 19 // 13 20 17 _ 4 1 18 _ 19 17 1 20 19 5 _ 15 22 - 5 9 11 9 3 5 _ 16 1 17 * // 15 11 4 5 17 _ ♦ 10 13 1 2 5 _ 9 12 _ 11 15 10 10 9 3 5 13 _ 1 17 // : 14 11 1 21 _ 9 13 _ 9 12 12 11 9 14 5 17 _ 17 20 ˌ // 14 11 1 21 _ 9 13 _ 9 12 12 11 9 14 5 17 _ 17 20 * // // ¡ 18 19 9 11 11 5 _ 13 1 22 19 ˌ 5 9 11 9 3 5 _ 13 1 22 19 ! * // ♦ 3 15 19 19 5 18 _ ♦ 18 24 13 ˛ 24 , 8 8 9 5 _ 11 1 22 19 // 11 9 5 2 ' _ 1 20 18 _ ♦ 4 5 9 13 5 12 _ ♦ 3 15 5 19 19 11 9 22 5 13 _ 12 20 13 4 ˌ // 4 1 _ 14 11 1 5 3 19 _ 20 13 18 _ 4 9 5 _ 17 5 19 19 5 13 4 5 _ 18 19 20 13 4 ' * // ¡ ♦ 22 17 9 18 19 _ 9 13 _ ♦ 4 5 9 13 5 17 _ 3 5 2 20 17 19 ! * // ¡ ♦ 22 17 9 18 19 _ 9 13 _ ♦ 4 5 9 13 5 17 _ 3 5 2 20 17 19 ! * // // ¡ 18 19 9 11 11 5 _ 13 1 22 19 ˌ 5 9 11 9 3 5 _ 13 1 22 19 ! ; // ˛ 4 9 5 : 4 5 17 _ 5 11 19 _ 5 9 11 _ 3 5 2 17 1 22 19 ˌ // 1 20 18 _ 4 5 18 _ 9 12 12 5 11 18 _ 3 15 11 4 5 13 5 13 _ 24 5 13 // 20 13 18 _ 4 5 17 _ 3 13 1 4 5 13 _ 21 20 5 11 11 5 _ 11 1 5 18 18 19 _ 18 7 ' 13 // : ♦ 9 7 18 20 18 _ 9 13 _ 12 5 13 14 5 13 - 3 5 18 19 1 11 19 ˌ // ♦ 9 7 18 20 18 _ 9 13 _ 12 5 13 14 5 13 - 3 5 18 19 1 11 19 * // // ¡ 18 19 9 11 11 5 _ 13 1 22 19 ˌ 5 9 11 9 3 5 _ 13 1 22 19 ! * // 8 8 15 _ 18 9 22 _ 5 20 19 _ 1 11 11 5 _ 12 1 22 19 // 8 1 5 19 5 17 11 9 22 5 17 _ 11 9 5 2 5 _ 5 17 3 15 18 18 ˌ // 20 13 4 _ 1 11 18 _ 2 17 20 4 5 17 _ 20 11 4 - 8 15 11 11 _ 20 12 14 11 15 18 18 ; // : ♦ 9 7 18 20 18 _ 4 9 5 _ 8 15 5 11 10 5 17 _ 4 5 17 _ 8 8 5 11 19 ˌ // ♦ 9 7 18 20 18 _ 4 9 5 _ 8 15 5 11 10 5 17 _ 4 5 17 _ 8 8 5 11 19 * // // ¡ 18 19 9 11 11 5 _ 13 1 22 19 ˌ 5 9 11 9 3 5 _ 13 1 22 19 ! * // 11 1 13 3 5 _ 18 22 15 13 _ 20 13 18 _ 2 5 4 1 22 19 ˌ // 1 11 18 _ 4 5 17 _ ♦ 5 17 17 _ 8 15 12 _ 3 17 9 12 12 5 _ 2 5 21 17 5 9 19 ˌ // 9 13 _ 4 5 17 _ 8 1 5 19 5 17 _ 20 17 - 3 17 1 20 5 17 _ 6 5 9 19 // : 1 11 11 5 17 _ 8 8 5 11 19 _ 14 15 13 20 13 3 _ 8 5 17 9 5 18 18 ˌ // 1 11 11 5 17 _ 8 8 5 11 19 _ 14 15 13 20 13 3 _ 8 5 17 9 5 18 18 * // // ¡ 18 19 9 11 11 5 _ 13 1 22 19 ˌ 5 9 11 9 3 5 _ 13 1 22 19 ! * // 9 17 19 5 13 _ 7 17 18 19 _ 10 20 13 4 - 3 5 12 1 22 19 // 4 20 17 22 _ 4 5 17 _ 5 13 3 5 11 ¡ 1 11 11 7 11 20 9 1 ! // 19 24 5 13 19 _ 5 18 _ 11 1 20 19 _ 2 5 9 _ 21 5 17 13 5 _ 20 13 4 _ 13 1 ⁑ // ¡ ♦ 22 17 9 18 19 _ 4 5 17 _ ♦ 17 5 19 19 5 17 _ 9 18 19 _ 4 1 ! * // ¡ ♦ 22 17 9 18 19 _ 4 5 17 _ ♦ 17 5 19 19 5 17 _ 9 18 19 _ 4 1 !

Comment: Is this your own cipher, or did you get it from somewhere?

Comment: Rather my own, but the cipher part is too trivial to be original.

Comment: Could we know what language this is in?

Comment: This is the second part. Well known language, but written in a nonstandard way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a

> german text:
>  
>  Replace each number with the corresponding greek letter (1 = $\alpha$, 2 = $\beta$, ...) and write down their transcription. Furthermore, underscores can be replaced by space and the diamond signals an upper case letter. (Thanks to @MOehm for the hint with the greek letters and the diamond)

You'll end up with this text

> ```
> das ist Deutschˌ¿wissen Sie?* 
> leute sprechen Deutsch in Deutschland
> (und in Oesterreichˌund auch in:Schweizzˌund Luksenburg)*
> ich offe˛dass Sie versteen das*
> ich benuzze das Griechische alphabet mit meiner eigenen ortographie und interpunktion*
> ich spreche Deutsch nicht ser gutˌaber das ist die bekannteste sprache in der welt˛die ich mag*
> ich offe˛dass ich nicht zu viele feler gemacht eabe⁂
> die tiere sind zum beispiel:maeuserˌkazzenˌundeˌkueeˌund werde⁂
> am ende ein weinachts-lied(die ich nicht ganz versve)⁑
>
> ¡stille nachtˌeilige nacht!*
> //alles schlaeftˌeinsam wacht
> //nur das traute och-eilige par*
> //older Knabe im lokkigen ar
> //:schlaf in immlischer ruˌ
> //schlaf in immlischer ru*
> //
> //¡stille nachtˌeilige nacht!*
> //Gottes Son˛o,wie lacht
> //lieb' aus Deinem Goettlichen mundˌ
> //da schlaegt uns die rettende stund'*
> //¡Christ in Deiner geburt!*
> //¡Christ in Deiner geburt!*
> //
> //¡stille nachtˌeilige nacht!;
> //˛die:der elt eil gebrachtˌ
> //aus des immels goldenen oen
> //uns der gnaden fuelle laesst se'n
> //:Iesus in menschen-gestaltˌ
> //Iesus in menschen-gestalt*
> //
> //¡stille nachtˌeilige nacht!*
> //wo sich eut alle macht
> //vaeterlicher liebe ergossˌ
> //und als bruder uld-voll umschloss;
> //:Iesus die voelker der weltˌ
> //Iesus die voelker der welt*
> //
> //¡stille nachtˌeilige nacht!*
> //lange schon uns bedachtˌ
> //als der Err vom grimme befreitˌ
> //in der vaeter ur-grauer zeit
> //:aller welt schonung veriessˌ
> //aller welt schonung veriess*
> //
> //¡stille nachtˌeilige nacht!*
> //irten erst kund-gemacht
> //durch der engel¡alleluia!
> //toent es laut bei ferne und na⁑
> //¡Christ der Retter ist da!*
> //¡Christ der Retter ist da!
> ```

which is german and translates to

> This is german, you know? 
>  People speak german in Germany (and in Austria, Switzerland and Luxembourg)
>  I hope you understand that I'm using the greek alphabet with my own ortography and interpunction.
>  I don't speak german very well but it's the most common language that I like. 
>  I hope I didn't make too many errors. 
>  The animals, for example, are: mice, cats, dogs, cows and horses.
>  Finally a christmas song (which I don't understand completely)
>  [the german lyrics for 'silent night']

Note, that

> I tried to keep a good balance between the difference between the pronounciation of the words and their correct spelling. Quite a few words are not spelled correctly, although their pronounication is just fine.

Comment: The numbers in the original text refer to the Greek alphabet. Note how there are no 25s and 26s: The Greek alphabet has only 24 letters. That also explains why all ch's are rendered as h: The 22nd letter of the Greek alphabet is chi (χ). The sch is represented by xi (ξ).

Comment: Orthography and interpunction are as I described, although thanks to your transcription, I have already found one typo in my text and I could misinterpret the part I do not understand completely. @MOehm Yes. Using this, you can recognise a little more information — notation of Os and Es is not random. I hope I did it correctly. With your addition I can accept Christoph's answer.

Comment: Oh, and the diamond means that the next letter is a capital letter.

Comment: @MOehm Yes. As you see, their use is much different from standard German.

Comment: @MOehm that makes perfectly sense. And it removes a dozen spelling errors if the 22nd letter is translated to a 'ch'. I'll update the answer accordingly.